# Check if a template tag is loaded in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

Is there a way to check if a template tag exists before using the template tag?

In other words, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
{% load my_custom_tags %}
...
{% ifloaded my_custom_tags %}
  {% some_custom_tag %}
{% endifloaded %}
```

Comment: Why? What happens if you do `{% load some_tag_library_that_does_not_exist %}`?

Comment: A TemplateSyntaxError is thrown. I have an application that requires 3rd party apps. I would like to make some of them optional depending on the functionality needed at a given time. I would rather not have many different templates for the same page, each one with a different combination of possible installed applications along with views to figure out which of the templates to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own, custom tag, that would check, if loaded tag is in the current context.

Here are docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/